# Не проходит редирект header()

Tags: php, сервер, битрикс, header

Здравствуйте!
В имеющимся скрипте при потпытке редиректа через функцию `header('Location: https://cp.unisender.com/ru/before_subscribe?email={{email}}')` ничего не происходит, показывается просто пустой белый экран, но данные отправляются. Если перейдёте по этой ссылке, то увидите вот такое окно [image: окно]
Собственно у меня 2 вопроса:

1. Заменяется ли {{email}} на реальный email?
2. Почему не происходит редирект?

Я пробовал различные `response_code` вставлять, но не помогает.

Знаю про отправку заголовков до вызова функции, но не понимаю, происходит ли это тут, и если происходит, то как исправить ситуацию не нарушая логику скрипта?

```
<?php
// экспорт контакта в unisender
// ключ доступа к API unisender (из Личного Кабинета)
$api_key = "somekey";
// Данные о новом подписчике
$user_email = $_POST['email'];
$user_name = $_POST['name'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$user_lists = $_POST['user_lists'];
$user_tag = urlencode("Added using API");
// Создаём POST-запрос
$POST = array(
    'api_key' => $api_key,
    'list_ids' => $user_lists,
    'fields[email]' => $user_email,
    'fields[phone]' => $phone,
    'fields[Name]' => $user_name
);
// Устанавливаем соединение
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $POST);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,
    'http://api.unisender.com/ru/api/subscribe?format=json');
$result = curl_exec($ch);

if ($result) {
    // Раскодируем ответ API-сервера
    $jsonObj = json_decode($result);

    if (null === $jsonObj) {
        // Ошибка в полученном ответе
        echo "Invalid JSON";

    } elseif (!empty($jsonObj->error)) {
        // Ошибка добавления пользователя
        echo "An error occured: " . $jsonObj->error . "(code: " . $jsonObj->code . ")";

    } else {
        // Новый пользователь успешно добавлен
        header('Location: https://cp.unisender.com/ru/before_subscribe?email={{email}}');

    }
} else {
    // Ошибка соединения с API-сервером
    echo "API access error";
}

 ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Нет, конечно. Чтобы он заменялся - нужен код, который будет заменять
2. Предполагаю ,что это из-за отсутствия заголовка Status: `header("Status: 302 Found");`

Раз у Вас Битрикс, есть другой путь: подключить его и использовать функцию [LocalRedirect](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/functions/other/localredirect.php)

Comment: Ну сам сайт на битриксе, но это по сути просто скрипт, лежащий в папке. В этом скрипте функция LocalRedirect будет работать? Я попробовал, всё равно белый экран, и с header("Status: 302 Found"); тоже белый экран

Comment: а какой стату с у страницы? Его можно посмотреть через DevTools. Возможно, у вас 500-я

Comment: Всегда уходит в 200 OK. Моежт curl отпарвляет заголовки, и потом второй раз они уже не отправляются?

Comment: CURL работает (отсылает заголовки и прочее) с хостом юнисендера, а не с браузером. У меня обоснованные идеи исчерпались - надо глазами смотреть и лично копаться в коде.